# Running into problems with running null model of genetic drift in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to wrangle a basic model of genetic drift in R.
However, every time I try to run the program it won't stop, and I have to manually stop it.

My complete code:

```
trials <- 100 #initialize the number of times you'll generate the time to fixation

fixation <- trials #Create a vector that records the number of generations until fixation of the alleles.

genVector <- numeric(trials) 

for(i in 1:trials){

  pop <- c(rep('a',20), rep('b',20)) #Initialize the population with equal numbers of both a and b alleles, for twenty individuals, or 40 alleles.

  genTime <- 1 #Number of generations

  freq <- length(pop[grep('a', pop)])/length(pop)

  while(freq > 0 | freq < 1){ #While the frequency of a in the population is greater than 0 or less than 1, perform the following calculations 

    pop <- sample(pop, length(pop), replace = TRUE) #Randomly select 40 alleles with constant replacement

    freq <- length(pop[grep('a', pop)])/length(pop)

    genTime <- genTime + 1 #Add one to the generation time

  }

  genVector[i] <- genTime

}
```

I believe I have isolated the problem to the while loop I am using, within the for loop. I have no idea why it won't stop running though. Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your while loop, you have an `OR` logical operator `|` when it should be `AND`, `&`.  Your loop will keep on running if freq is positive.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim! It works just fine now, and I will keep your advice in mind for the future!